# angular $http post login with headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to AngularJS and i am encountering an issue with the system i am developing.

i got this error

> ReferenceError: $http is not defined

when i tried to use this code.

```js
'use strict';

myApp.factory('loginService', function() {
  return {
    login: function(user) {
      var $promise = $http.post(
        'http://unexus-api-dev-3urcgetdum.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/login', {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token token=\"bc0a3f1cfeaf2d9ad98edd005a756ae9\"'
          },
          user
        });

      $promise.then(function(msg) {
        if (msg.data == 'success')
          console.log('success login');
        else
          console.log('failed login');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

i know that my code is messy but i hope you guys can help me.

Comment: change myApp.factory('loginService', function() to myApp.factory('loginService', function($http)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pass the dependency $http in your factory.

```
myApp.factory('loginService',['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    login: function(user) {
      var $promise = $http.post(
        'http://unexus-api-dev-3urcgetdum.elasticbeanstalk.com/users/login', {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Token token=\"bc0a3f1cfeaf2d9ad98edd005a756ae9\"'
          },
          user
        });

      $promise.then(function(msg) {
        if (msg.data == 'success')
          console.log('success login');
        else
          console.log('failed login');
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```